# Friending a dependent template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a case in my code where I need to make a dependent template class a friend, but I think I've exhausted the possibilities and none of them work. Is this possible to do at all? If so, how?

Simplest example:

```
struct Traits {
    template <typename T>
    struct Foo {
        typedef typename T::bar* type;
    };
};

template <typename T>
class Bar
{
    typedef int bar;
    // need to make T::Foo<Bar> a friend somehow?
    typedef typename T::template Foo<Bar>::type type; // won't compile because bar is private... 
                                                      // suppose I cannot make bar public.


    type val;
};

int main() {
    Bar<Traits> b;
}
```

Comment: It makes little sense. If you are offering friendship to *any* class that is willing to do as little as use itself as your template parameter, just make everything `public`. Anyone who wants to grab your privates can become your friend anyway. Why bother? But you can say (in C++11) `friend typename T::template Foo<Bar>;` if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Traits {
    template <typename T>
    struct Foo {
        typedef typename T::bar* type;
    };
};

template <typename T>
class Bar
{
    typedef int bar;
    friend typename T::template Foo<Bar>;
    typedef typename T::template Foo<Bar>::type type;
    type val;
};

int main() {
    Bar<Traits> b;
}
```

Comment: Works on gcc 4.7.3, not on 4.6.4 ("a class-key must be used when declaring a friend"). I'm guessing this is just a bug in the older gcc?

Comment: @Barry, more like not-yet-implemented rather than a bug, but yes, I tested it on 4.8.1 and works fine.

Comment: `friend typename` is a C++11 feature, not available in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
using my_friend=typename T::template Foo<Bar>;
friend my_friend;
```

inside your class ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd07b4abe3e4aa35))

Comment: Or directly `friend typename T::template Foo<Bar>;` works too

Comment: @texasbruce yes, but sometimes I prefer typedefs to make things better readable (at least for me). Templates an can become very complicated and in combination with friends (or template friends) it is something which I don't see offen, so I would prefer something more elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to compile with this inserted at the point of your comment:

```
friend struct Traits::Foo<Bar>;
```

Comment: He wants the Traits as a template parameter

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, wouldn't you be better off with something like this?

```
template <typename T>
class Bar;

struct Traits
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  struct Foo
  {
    typedef Bar<T> bar_type;
    typedef typename bar_type::bar* type;
  };
};

template <typename T>
class Bar
{
  typedef int bar;
  typedef Bar self_type;
  typedef struct Traits::template Foo<T> traits_type;

  friend traits_type;

  typedef typename traits_type::type type;

  type val;
};


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  Bar<Traits> b;
}
```

It is alot safer than allowing anything that contains a public typedef type to be your friend, though it is all...weird.